# Android,Problems with Fragment hierarchy

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I currently have a fragment with a view pager inside, one of its three childern has a recycler view with selectable items, when an item is selected, another fragment,with a recycler view, is showed (it is an indipendent fragment and not showed in the same view pager).

[image: My situation is this]

What i'm trying to do, is to replace F1 with F2 from F1,1. When F2.onCreateView() is invoked i obtain this error:

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

In order to provide a FragmentManager to the FragmentPagerAdapter, F1.getChildFragmentManger() is invoked when F1 starts.

The steps I'm following "when an item is selected from F1,1" are:

1) get the parent fragment

2) get the FragmentManager from parent fragment

3) replace parent fragment (F1) with F2.

I suspect the problem is the way i'm trying to change fragments, i also tried, always from F1,1, to get the FragmentManager directly from the activity. I know, maybe it is a very bad idea but i had to try something...

this is the F1,1 method that is invoked when you select an item from the recycler view.

```
@Override
public void navigateToProductListView(Vendor vendor, Category category) {
    Bundle argument = new Bundle();
    argument.putParcelable(Vendor.TAG, vendor);
    argument.putParcelable(Category.TAG, category);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragment().getFragmentManager();

    ProductListFragment productListFragment = (ProductListFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ProductListFragment.TAG);

    if (productListFragment == null) {
        productListFragment = new ProductListFragment();
        Log.i("ProductListFragment", "was null");
    }

    productListFragment.setArguments(argument);
    Transitions.replaceFragment(fragmentManager, productListFragment, ProductListFragment.TAG, true);
}
```

and onCreateView() of F2 that throws the exception

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_list, container, false);

    mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, root);

    ListHelper.init(getActivity(), mRecyclerView);

    Log.i("ProductListFragment","onCreateView()");

    return root;
}
```

this is the code of my Transitions class, i use only one activity so the FrameLayout used to hold fragments is always the same

```
public static void replaceFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Fragment fragment, String tag, boolean addToBackStack) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Slide enterTransition = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        enterTransition.setDuration(500);
        fragment.setEnterTransition(enterTransition);
        fragment.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
    }

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
    if (addToBackStack) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Through callback methods, You can switch the parent fragment from child fragment.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: Is Transitions your custom class? And what is in your replaceFragment method?

Comment: Yes Transitions is a custom class, it just replaces fragments but just to be clear i'll post the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragment().getFragmentManager();` this statement gives you the parent private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment. 
Try this `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragment().getActivity().getFragmentManager();`

Comment: thank you for your answer , unfortunately i have already tried to obtain the fragment manager directly from the activity but it does not work

Comment: are you sure all of those fragments are belongs to same activity?

Comment: absolutely yes, the activity is only one and always the same. F1 and F2 are directly attached to the activity and F1,1, F1,2, F1,3 are in the view pager declared in F1 and handled by the child fragment manager of F1

Comment: I'm an idiot, i solved the problem. The issue was not caused by the fragments, the cause of all evils was the RecyclerViewAdapter in F2. I forgot to put the attachToRoot flag in onCreateViewHolder() method...sorry and thanks for your patience!!!